# Gridded data time series forecasting with Keras

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to forecast 5 days precipitation, but the model doesn't seem to be working some how. I am using convLSTM. My input is 5 dimensional (batch, time-steps, latitude, longitude, channels).

```
seq = Sequential()
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(None,50, 40, 1), padding='same', return_sequences=True))

seq.add(BatchNormalization())

seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
               padding='same', return_sequences=True))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())

seq.add(Lambda(lambda x: x[: ,-5: ,: ,: ,:]))

seq.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
           activation='sigmoid',
           padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
```

I am a bit confused. I think the architecture does this,

```
                     0 0 0 0 0
           | | | | | | | | | |
           0 0 0 0 0 0
           | | | | | |
       ....0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is it right?
If not, suggest changes.